# How can I set position of cursor to the above line in an edit text when pressing up arrow of a customized android keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I set position of cursor to the above line in an edit text when pressing  up arrow of a customized android keyboard.Is there any options to directly specify line number using edit text setselection? I am a newbie in android. Please help me out..